# How to autofit canvas in parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a canvas inside div:

```
<div class="preview"><canvas id="cropped" width="2480" height="2003"></canvas></div>
```

Div block is less then canvas side. How to autofit canvas by two cases:

1. canvas width autofit proportional of parent width div
2. canvas height autofit proportional of parent height div

I tried this way:

```
public autofit = (orientation: RegistryOrientation) => {
    let previews = document.getElementsByClassName('preview');

    if (previews.length > 0) {
        let preview = previews[0];
        let width = preview.clientWidth;
        let height = preview.clientHeight;

        if (orientation === RegistryOrientation.album) {
            this.imgCanvas.style.width = width + 'px';
            this.imgCanvas.style.height = 'auto';
        } else if (orientation === RegistryOrientation.book) {
            this.imgCanvas.style.height = height + 'px';
            this.imgCanvas.style.width = 'auto';
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the '%' symbol to denote proportional height of the parent. For example (in your CSS):

```css
#cropped {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Of course, instead of using a CSS file or style tag, you can also opt for just calling `cropped.style.width` and `cropped.style.height`

Comment: I want to place whole canvas proportional. So I did not get why you set 80% for height and 100 for width

Comment: That were just some example percentages, to show you can make it proportional (and not just 100%). If I now, in my local test file, set the `div` dimensions to `50vw` and `50vh` (to make it 50% of the screen dimensions), the canvas automatically fills 100% of the width therein, and 80% of the height. I think you should be able to use percentages instead of pixels to solve your issue :)

Comment: just make sure, canvas considers it's own width and height as input

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is what you want:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div><canvas width="1000" height="1000"></canvas></div>
```

Comment: I have 3/4 ration, or width has 4 or height has 4. depends of case

Comment: Should work as long as you change `aspect-ratio` and the canvas's width & height.